# iOS Localization with Fastlane translation plugin

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, localization, fastlane

Im trying to setup a flow where I have translations in a Google Docs and download these to .strings files and generates a Translations swift struct with constants for each NSLocalizedString key. Im stuck with the Authentication part:

**Installed the translation plugin**

```
fastlane add_plugin translation
```

**Created lane in Fastfile**

```
  lane :translations do
      translation(
        doc_id:'PASTED_FROM_GOOGLE_DOC_URL',
        key: 0,
        ios_output_paths:{
          'DummyProject/da.lproj/Localizable.strings' => 1,
          'DummyProject/en.lproj/Localizable.strings' => 2
        },
        swift_struct_path: 'DummyProject/Translations.swift',
        config_path: "fastlane/config.json"
     )
  end
```

**config.json file content**

```
{
  "client_id": "136678564448-ta8gq3t1ipcpb9n97s0gbnee1rl94l8q.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_secret": "_LDTyiL4u0gHmU2QoasZCBI4",
  "scope": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
  ],
  "refresh_token": "1/kALA83pkHtJD1jFXnlLsQxrVKoz4KW77NFVVNTLl7d4"
}
```

How do I acquire `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `refresh_token` so the plugin can download translations from Google doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/master/doc/authorization.md#on-behalf-of-you-command-line-authorization][1] to get client_id, client_secret for the config.json

A project must be created to make OAuth 2.0 client credentials

Refresh token can be fetched the first time if the field is omitted in the `config.json` file and the script is asking you to go a special web page.